# Rails. Authlogic. Ошибка при logout'е

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

Доброго времени суток всем.
Такая проблема. 
Имеется приложение, в котором аутентификация осуществляется при помощи гема [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). Авторизованный пользователь попадает на страницу администрирования. 
Если производить ajax запросы или просто, сразу, нажать кнопку logout, то сессия заканчивается, попадаем на рут страницу и все хорошо.
Но, если перед нажатием кнопки logout просто обновить страницу, по f5 или кнопкой браузера, то при последующем нажатии кнопки logout получаем ошибку о том, что csrf токен не валиден. Если снова зайти на /admin и сразу нажать logout, то все срабатывает хорошо.
С чем это может быть связано, как работают csrf токены?

UserSessionController#destroy

```
    def destroy
    if current_user_session
        current_user_session.destroy
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Всего доброго!"
    else
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "Вы не авторизованы."
    end
end
```

Кнопка logout

```
= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete, class: 'logout btn btn-xs btn-danger'
```

Роутер

```
    delete '/logout', to: 'user_sessions#destroy', as: :logout
```

За ранее спасибо!